# File functions not working as expected with AWS PHP Streamwrapper

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-php-sdk

I have this PHP code running in two different environments: an on-prem server running PHP 5.6 and an EC2 instance running PHP 7.2.

```
$filepath = 's3://'.$this->s3Bucket.'/'.$key;

$this->s3Client->registerStreamWrapper();

echo "file exists ".file_exists($filepath);
```

The file functions (e.g., file_exists and readfile) don't appear to work the same way in both environments. In the on-prem server, they work as expected: that is, file_exists returns true for known file, as expected. But on the EC2 instance, file_exists returns false.

The $filepath var looks like `s3://my-bucket/a-prefix/another-prefix/LlPIpMvDdmX6i38.pdf`. The S3 client and stream wrapper all appear to be correct with var_dump. The only thing I can find is that the PHP file functions simply don't work as expected.

I also tried this line in the EC2 instance:

```
 filesize($filepath);
```

And go this warning: filesize(): stat failed for s3://...LlPIpMvDdmX6i38.pdf

Is there something I missing in the EC2 set-up that is preventing Streamwrapper from working?

Comment: Are you on Windows by any chance? If so, your file encoding is wrong. UTF-8 all the things!

Comment: most file functions don't work on streams. `filesize` and `file_exists` in particular do not work on streams.

Comment: Sidenote: Why don't you just use [`headObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#headobject) since you're already using the AWS SDK API ?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Here are my replies: 

I'm not on Windows.

The on-prem environment has file functions working perfectly well with the AWS S3 Streamwrapper. Something is different in the new EC2 instance, or maybe it's the PHP version?

We are moving some existing code to AWS with as little refactoring as possible. Might have to recode file reading without the assistance of Streamwrapper. :S

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the error in the error logs with the help of a colleague.

```
PHP Warning:  readfile(): s3:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0
```

Setting allow_url_fopen=1 fixed the problem.

Comment: Thank you... would have been there forever finding that! :)